# Xcode Interface Builder Segue Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, segue

I have added a few segues between different view controllers through the interface builder. However the transition animation is always the same (view is pulled up from bottom). How can I have different segues using different transitions like pulled in from the left or right. So far I can only seem to find results relating to building custom transitions where as I would happily use existing ones like the left/right transition seen when using the navigation controller.

Comment: Not sure if that what you want, but it seem that you're presenting view controller. Try to change segue type to push.

Comment: I am already using push, I just want to change the transition effect

Answer (score 1):

you can use some predefined animations..

Just click the segue from the storyboard, and in the right side panel, click the **show attributes inspector** icon, and then you will see the dropdown for choosing animation like shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Does that change the transition effect? I thought that was related to how to view controller is placed onto the view hierarchy?